# Can I automatically save datetime for every entry in my spatialite tabel?

Tags: qgis, date

I'm using QGIS and SpatiaLite. Is it possible to store date and time in a field "datetime" for every entry automatically - maybe with some python code? Already existing datetime should not be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note: This is a pure SpatiaLite solution, contains no Python code, and can be fitted (following the logic similarity) in any  GIS application context**

I'll show you one easy way to solve your problem:

1) Because I already have a SpatiaLite table, (called `shotpoints`) from a previous demonstration, my first intention is to add a new datetime column, as you required:

```sql
ALTER TABLE "shotpoints"
ADD COLUMN dt datetime
```

[image]

2) Let's see this vector layer inside QGIS:

[image]

3) It is time to create a trigger for updating the datetime column:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER insert_datetime AFTER  INSERT ON shotpoints
  BEGIN
    UPDATE shotpoints SET dt = DATETIME('NOW') WHERE rowid = new.rowid;
  END;
```

[image]

4) I'm verifying the trigger was created:

```sql
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master;
```

[image]

5) Finally, we need to insert a new point and to verify the trigger is working:

[image]

Everything works ok! Case closed!

Comment: It works - thats exactly what I was looking for! Thank you